# Using Real To Tap() the "Ok" button on an Alert

Tags: xamarin, read-eval-print-loop, xamarin.uitest

I am using Xamarin Forms / Xamarin.UITest and I have a greeting Alert I want to tap the **ok** button own my alert using app.Tap('**your query here**')

```
                                                           [CalabashRootView]                                                                [UIWindow > ... > UILayoutContainerView]                                          [UINavigationTransitionView > ... > Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_Platform_DefaultRenderer]                                                                          [Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_Platform_DefaultRenderer]                             [Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_BoxRenderer]                                        [Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_Platform_DefaultRenderer]                             [Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_BoxRenderer]                                        [Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_ImageRenderer]                           
        [UIImageView] id: "uscourts.png"

            [_UIAlertControllerActionView > UIView] label: "Ok"
              [UILabel] label: "Ok",  text: "Ok"
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple query for the Text should do the work

```
app.Tap(c => c.Text("Ok"))
```